# Swift- import module working in one file, but not in another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, module, stripe-payments

Just to clarify, the Stripe module is giving the error that there is no module named Stripe. Here is what I tried:

File 1 (working in this file):

```
import Foundation
import Stripe
import FirebaseFunctions

let StripeApi = _StripeApi()

class _StripeApi : NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {
```

File 2 (not working in this file):

```
import UIKit
import Stripe
import FirebaseFunctions

class CheckoutVC: UIViewController, CartItemDelegate {
```

In addition, the same file gives this error: **Value of type 'STPPaymentConfiguration' has no member 'createCardSources'**

```
func setupStripeConfig() {
        let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared()
        config.createCardSources = true
        config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
        config.requiredShippingAddressFields = [.postalAddress]

        let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeApi)
        paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .default())

        paymentContext.paymentAmount = StripeCart.total
        paymentContext.delegate = self
        paymentContext.hostViewController = self

    }
```

If anyone could put me on the right track, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? `createCardSources` wasn't added till v12.1.0: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/ebdf362a00c7facb956d0b289cbd8385312d9af2/CHANGELOG.md#1210-2018-02-05

Comment: @PaulAsjes 13.2

Answer (score 0):

You're refactored code, worked in iOS 12 and above.

```
func setupStripeConfig() {
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared
    config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
    config.requiredShippingAddressFields = [.postalAddress]
    
    let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeApi)
    paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .defaultTheme)
    
    paymentContext.paymentAmount = StripeCart.total
    paymentContext.delegate = self
    paymentContext.hostViewController = self
}
```

you can take this part `config.createCardSources = true` out and all the errors would be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `stripeClient` File:

```
import Foundation
import Stripe

class StripeClient {
    
    static let sharedClient = StripeClient()
    
    var baseURLString : String? = nil
    
    var baseURL: URL {
        
        if let URLString = self.baseURLString, let url = URL(string: URLString){
            return url
        }
        else {
            fatalError()
        }
    }
    
    func createAndConfirmPayment(_ token: STPToken, amount: Int, completion: @escaping(_ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        
        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("charge")
        
        let params: [String : Any] = ["stripeToken" : token.tokenId, "amount" : amount, "description" : Constants.defaultDescription, "currency" : Constants.defaultCurrency] 

}
```

Add this to your `AppDelegate.Swift`:

```
// MARK: - Strip Init

func StripeInit() {
    
//        STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = Constants.publishedKey

    
    STPAPIClient.shared().publishableKey = Constants.publishedKey
    StripeClient.sharedClient.baseURLString = Constants.baseURLString
}
}
```

Then call it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

I've created `CardInfoViewController` which contains the below:

```
import UIKit
import Stripe

protocol CardInfoViewControllerDelegate {
    
    func doneButtonPressed (_ token: STPToken )
    
    func cancelButtonPressed ()
    
}



class CardInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var doneButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    
    let paymentCardTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()
    
    var delegate: CardInfoViewControllerDelegate?
    
    // MARK: - Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

        
        paymentCardTextField.delegate = self
        // Modifying card textfield
        
        view.addSubview(paymentCardTextField)
        paymentCardTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: paymentCardTextField, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: doneButtonOutlet, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 30))
        
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: paymentCardTextField, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20))

        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: paymentCardTextField, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func cancelButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.cancelButtonPressed()
        dismissView()
    }
    

    
    @IBAction func doneButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        
        processCard()
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Support funcs
    
    private func dismissView() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    private func processCard () {
        
        let cardParams = STPCardParams()
        cardParams.number = paymentCardTextField.cardNumber
        cardParams.expMonth = paymentCardTextField.expirationMonth
        cardParams.expYear = paymentCardTextField.expirationYear
        cardParams.cvc = paymentCardTextField.cvc
//        cardParams.addressZip = paymentCardTextField.
         
        STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: cardParams) { (token, error) in
            
            if error == nil {
                print("Finally we have a token which is \(token!)")
                self.delegate?.doneButtonPressed(token!)
                
                self.dismissView()
            }
            else {
                print("error processing card token \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Payment extension

extension CardInfoViewController: STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate {
    
    func paymentCardTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: STPPaymentCardTextField) {
        
        doneButtonOutlet.isEnabled = textField.isValid
        if doneButtonOutlet.isEnabled == true {
            doneButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        }
        else {
            doneButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3333333433, green: 0.3333333433, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1)

        }
    }
}
```